# php get return variable(s) from function list inside a class

Tags: php

How can i access either a **single** or **entire multiple return** from a function inside a class?

Normally from a function, i can access multiple returns like

```
list($name, $number ) = functionFromSomeClass($a, $b, $c);
$n1 = $name;
$n2 = $number;
```

but when this function is inside a class, i seem to be having problems access the entire or single return

```
class MyClass{

    public function newFunc( $var_1, $var_2 ) {

        require_once('someOtherClass.php');
        // process


        list($name, $number ) = functionFromSomeOtherClass($a, $b, $c);
    }


}
```

then to access:

```
$myclass = new MyClass;
$name = $myclass->newFunc($q, $w)->$name;
```

or, how would i get the entire list return?

```
$myclass = new MyClass;
list($name, $number) = $myclass->newFunc($q, $w);
```

Comment: `list($name, $number ) = functionFromSomeClass($a, $b, $c);` This works? In PHP? Cool!

Comment: I hope calling require_once('someOtherClass.php'); inside the function itself is a mistake because you made the code up for this question. Else you should really move it completely outside of scope.

Comment: i see,  the reason was because of path, depending on the function the location can change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*If* I understand what you're saying, you are looking to pass the values of some other class and then pass them on in a different location when you call a function. You can do this in a few ways. One way, you'd be returning values in the function. Another way, you can declare public class variables like so:

```
class MyClass{
    public $name,$number;

    public function newFunc( $var_1, $var_2 ) {

        require_once('someOtherClass.php');
        // process


        list($this->name, $this->number ) = functionFromSomeOtherClass($a, $b, $c);
    }
}
```

That way when you're calling a function like so:

```
$myClass = new MyClass;
```

You can simply call a function and access variables here:

```
$myClass->newFunc($var1,$var2);
$n1 = $myClass->name;
$n2 = $myClass->number;
```

Again, the other option is just to return the results of the other class, like so:

```
class MyClass{
    public $name,$number;

    public function newFunc( $var_1, $var_2 ) {

        require_once('someOtherClass.php');
        // process
        $otherClass = new OtherClass;

        return $otherCLass->functionFromSomeOtherClass($a, $b, $c);
    }
}

$myClass = new MyClass;
list($name,$number) = $myClass->newFunc($var1,$var2);
```

If that's not what you're getting at, as I suggested in a comment, it would help to have a more detailed example.

Comment: thanks for all this,  since `otherClass` has multiple returns as well,  can you simply do a `return`?

Comment: However you'd like to do it is fine, either example. You could declare separate variables from an array in and outside of the class or pass a multidimensional array. The key to passing the variables in a class that's different from a function outside of a class is that you need to make them accessible outside of the class. To do that, you'll need to either return, or declare and assign a variable to a class variable.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to access to another function in a class you should:

```
$this->functionFromSomeOtherClass($a, $b, $c);
```

In other word:

```
class MyClass
{

    public function newFunc( $var_1, $var_2 ) {

        require_once('someOtherClass.php');
        // process

        $someotherclass = new someOtherClass();
        list($name, $number ) = $someotherclass->functionFromSomeOtherClass($a, $b, $c);
    }


}
```

Comment: thanks,  forgot to instantiate,  but then how do i get the return values from `newFunc`?

Comment: look at `GolezTrol` author.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to create an instance of the other class, or call it as a static function, depending on how the method is declared:

`someOtherClass.php`:

```
class OtherClass
{
    public function functionFromSomeOtherClass($a, $b, $c)
    {
         return $a + $b + $c;

    }

}
```

`MyClass.php`:

```
class MyClass{

    public function newFunc( $var_1, $var_2 ) {

        require_once('someOtherClass.php');

        // Instance call:
        $otherClass = new OtherClass();
        list($name, $number ) = $otherClass->functionFromSomeOtherClass($a, $b, $c);

        // Static call:
        list($name, $number ) = OtherClass::functionFromSomeOtherClass($a, $b, $c);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

When you use the syntax

```
list($var1, $var2, ...) = <expression>;
```

it just means that `<expression>` must evaluate to an array, and the variables will be assigned from successive elements of the array. `<expression>` can be any calculation, including function or method calls; you write it the same way as you would if it were being assigned normally. But if it's a function or method call, the function/method must return an array for this to be valid.

There's nothing special about using this when calling functions from another class.

Answer (score 1):

You are not even returning.

```
function get_multi() {
    return array(1, 2, 3);
}

list($a, $b, $c) = get_multi();
```

Comment: As Logan said, I don't see any return. It would help if you posted a more complete example. Right now it looks like (a) you are not returning, (b) you are not explaining what someOtherClass returns, (c) you don't have any $a, $b, or $c for someOtherClass. Without this information there are any number of things that could be going wrong that we would never be able to spot.